# Cannot see Hadoop UI which is running inside docker container, in browser

Tags: docker, hadoop, weave

I have a Hadoop cluster of three containers on three different hosts; the details are in following:
  First, I install "weave net" in my three hosts (150.20.11.133,150.20.11.136,150.20.11.157) via this command:

```
 sudo curl -L git.io/weave -o /usr/local/bin/weave
 sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/weave
 eval $(weave env)
```

Then I connected three host together via weave. In fact, I ran this command in three hosts:

For example in 150.20.11.133:

```
 Weave launch 150.20.11.136 150.20.11.157
```

After connecting three hosts together, I had to make **SSH** passwordless between Master and Workers. Therefore, I did there works:
In each host:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

In master:

```
 ssh-copy-id spark@172.28.10.136
 ssh-copy-id spark@172.28.10.157
 cat /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

As a result of that, I could run **SSH** without password from master host to slaves.

In each host, I built my Docker file which had configuration for hadoop then I ran that:

In Master:

```
 docker run -v /home/user/.ssh:/root/.ssh --privileged -p 52222:22 
 -e WEAVE_CIDR=10.32.0.1/12 -ti my-hadoop
```

In slave1:

```
 docker run -v /home/user/.ssh:/root/.ssh --privileged -p 52222:22 
 -e WEAVE_CIDR=10.32.0.2/12 -ti my-hadoop
```

In slave2:

```
 docker run -v /home/user/.ssh:/root/.ssh --privileged -p 52222:22 
 -e WEAVE_CIDR=10.32.0.3/12 -ti my-hadoop
```

In each container, I ran these commands:

```
 chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
 chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
 chown -R root ~/.ssh/
 chgrp -R root ~/.ssh/
 chmod -R 750 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

In master container, I ran this command to run **SSH localhost**:

```
 ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R localhost
```

Also, I started **SSH** service in each container node:

```
 service ssh restart
```

So, I could run **SSH** from master container to slaves without password.
For hadoop configuration, I did these works:
First in master node:

```
  hadoop namenode -format
```

**workers** had these contents in three contaiers:

```
  root@10.32.0.2
  root@10.32.0.3
```

**core-site.xml** had this contents in three containers:

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
       <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
       <value>hdfs://root@10.32.0.1:9000</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml** had these contents in three containers too:

```
   <configuration>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
   </configuration>
```

Then I ran this in master container:

```
   /opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

When I ran **jps** in each container, I received these results:
In Master container:

```
   483 SecondaryNameNode
   231 NameNode
   747 Jps
```

In each Worker:

```
   117 DataNode
   186 Jps
```

The problem is, I want to see Hadoop UI in browser. I run this URL, but it does not show anything:

```
    http://10.32.0.1:8088
```

By the way, I have already exposed these ports in docker file:

```
    EXPOSE 22 9000 8088 50070 50075 50030 50060
```

Would you please tell me how I can see Hadoop cluster UI in browser?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see datanodes in browser by adding these lines in **hdfs-site.xml**.

```
<property>
     <name>dfs.http.address</name>
     <value>10.32.0.1:50070</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
     <value>10.32.0.1:50090</value>
</property>
```

Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't start YARN by /opt/hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh

port 8088 is for YARN Web UI and 50070 is where you can see the HDFS status.

Comment: Dear @Newnius, I did not start **YARN**, because I am going to use Mesos for resource manager. Also, when I run **http://10.32.0.1:50070**, it does not show anything.

Comment: You can check the logs in  /opt/hadoop/logs/ see what happend

Comment: Also, ping 10.32.0.1 to see if you can connect to that node

Comment: I can ping to that node and ssh is run without any problems.

Comment: Dear @Newnius, I saw the log, everything was OK.

Comment: I think, it is related to Weave net IP. Because when I run container with **net host**, I can see hadoop UI, even though it does not show any nodes.

Comment: I know nothing about Weave and I usually use docker swarm. But you can take a look at https://github.com/newnius/Dockerfiles/tree/master/hadoop/2.7.4/config , I modified these 5 configuration files so that the cluster works fine.

Comment: Dear @Newnius,  many thanks. I will test that. Because I have to use Mesos and Marathon with Docker Compose,  I don't choose Docker Swarm.

Comment: Dear @Newnius, I test the config that you used; but still I cannot see any hadoop UI in my browser.

Comment: Logs do not show any error except : **Http request log for http.requests.namenode is not defined**.

Comment: Can you curl 50070 inside the namenode container?

Comment: If you mean this : **curl http://10.32.0.1:50070**. yes, I can do that and it shows me a html page with **Hadoop Administration** title.

Comment: Well, then it must be the fault of weave which is out of my scope. You can search how to expose ports in weave network

Comment: thank you for your help. Would you please tell me how you run hadoop UI in docker swarm? which address do you exactly write in your browser?

Comment: I just start another socks5 proxy to route the traffic and visit by the service name, say http://hadoop-master:50070 This post describes how to do that if you want to know https://blog.newnius.com/setup-distributed-hadoop-cluster-with-docker-step-by-step.html#Expose-the-WebUI